# Calling inline Javascript from codebehind on pageload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript block on my asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.debug = true;
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I call this from C# code behind?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", ???, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to call :

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "xyz();", true);
Keep your JavaScript in a function ;

Answer (score 0):

You might find help here on this question at MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5f09794-3224-4c9d-8453-688a303a9198/call-javascript-function-from-c-codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "sample", "<script 
    type="text/javascript">Sys.debug = true;var popup;Sys.require(Sys.components.popup,
    function () {popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {parentElementID: "target",});});
    </script>",false);
```